# Auto fill blank cells in a table based on the largest column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with 3 columns. I want to write a program which can find the number of rows in the largest column and fills the other blank columns up until the last row in the largest column. For example see the original and final table below. Column B has 5 rows so I want to fill in the blank rows in column A and C till the 5th row.

Original Table

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | BA | CA |
| AB | BB | CB |
|  | BC | CC |
|  | BD |  |
|  | BE |  |

Final Table

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | BA | CA |
| AB | BB | CB |
| AA | BC | CC |
| AB | BD | CA |
| AA | BE | CB |

I have tried using the autofill function within excel but that only autofills the blank cells with the above value. Instead I want to copy all the values in the each column and paste them until there are no blank cells left.
So instead of table 1 I want table 2:
Table 1:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | BA | CA |
| AB | BB | CB |
| AB | BC | CC |
| AB | BD | CC |
| AB | BE | CC |

Table 2:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | BA | CA |
| AB | BB | CB |
| **AA** | BC | CC |
| **AB** | BD | **CA** |
| **AA** | BE | **CB** |

My code so far:

```
Sub FillBlanks()
Dim userSelection As Range
Dim cell As Range
Set userSelection = Selection
For Each cell In UserSelection
    If cell = "" Then
        cell.FillDown
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly what range is being selected?

Comment: I am selecting the entire table from column A row 1 to column C row 5. On my excel sheet its A1:C6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try.

```vb
Sub FillBlanks()
    Dim userSelection As Range
    Dim cell As Range, r, c, arr, iPointer
    Set userSelection = Selection
    ' If the top-left cell of table is A1, get the table range
    ' Set userSelection = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arr = userSelection.Value
    For c = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
        iPointer = 1
        For r = 1 To UBound(arr)
            If arr(r, c) = "" Then
                arr(r, c) = arr(iPointer, c)
                iPointer = iPointer + 1
                If iPointer > UBound(arr) Then iPointer = 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
    userSelection.Value = arr
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you selected a range which just includes the last cell of the "full" column:

```vb
Sub FillBlanks()
    Dim col As Range, c As Range, lr As Long, rng As Range
    Set rng = Selection
    lr = rng.Rows(rng.Rows.Count).Row      'last selected row
    For Each col In Selection.Columns      'check each column
        Set c = col.Cells(col.Cells.Count).Offset(1).End(xlUp) 'last used cell in this column
        If c.Row < lr Then 'need to fill down?
            col.Parent.Range(col.Cells(1), c).AutoFill col
        End If
    Next col
End Sub
```